# Flatbuffer mutate doesn't change bytes

Tags: go, flatbuffers

I am running into a problem mutating a flatbuffer from bytes.  According to the flatbuffer documentation (https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/docs/source/Tutorial.md), you can
mutate fixed size fields, such as an int32.  And as you can see below, the generated golang TestMutate has a
MutateServerId() function.  My problem is that after I mutate it, the bytes don't seem to have changed.

Here is my flatbuffer table definition:

```
namespace foo;

table TestMutate {
    serverId:int32;
}
```

Here is a unit test I wrote:

```
func TestMutateFlatbuffer2(test *testing.T) {
    builder := flatbuffers.NewBuilder(1024)
    packageWalletStorageServicesRPC.TestMutateStart(builder)
    packageWalletStorageServicesRPC.TestMutateAddServerId(builder, 1)
    endMessage := packageWalletStorageServicesRPC.TestMutateEnd(builder)
    builder.Finish(endMessage)

    bytes := builder.FinishedBytes()
    testMutate := packageWalletStorageServicesRPC.GetRootAsTestMutate(bytes, 0)
    success := testMutate.MutateServerId(2)
    if !success {
        panic("Server id not mutated.")
    } else {
        logger.Logf(logger.INFO, "serverId mutated to:%d", testMutate.ServerId())
    }

    mutatedBytes := testMutate.Table().Bytes
    if string(mutatedBytes) == string(bytes) {
        panic("Bytes were not mutated.")
    }
}
```

Here is the output from the test.

```
=== RUN   TestMutateFlatbuffer2
2019/08/01 19:33:56.801926 foo_test.go:389   : [ I ]: serverId mutated to:2
--- FAIL: TestMutateFlatbuffer2 (0.00s)
panic: Bytes were not mutated. [recovered]
    panic: Bytes were not mutated.
```

Notice that it appears I've mutated the underlying structure, but when I get the bytes of the flatbuffer,
they're not changed.  Question 1:  Am I getting the bytes the correct way?  Question 2: If I'm getting them in the right way, why
are they not changed since the call to mutate seemed to succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test `string(mutatedBytes) == string(bytes)` fails because.. you are comparing the mutated buffer against itself. `bytes` refers to a buffer, that before your mutation contains a 1, and after it contains a 2. `mutatedBytes` points to the same buffer, and thus  also contains a 2. The fact that `testMutate.ServerId()` returns 2 should tell you that the buffer got mutated succesfully, because there is no other way it could return 2 :) You'd have to make a (deep) copy of `bytes` before the mutation if you wanted this comparison to show that the buffers are different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - your help is appreciated.  I independently figured last night some hours after posting the testing bug where I'm comparing the same array to itself.  There's two solutions, one of which is to copy the []byte as you suggest.  The flatbuffer table definition I posted is a simplification of my real table.  For me, the second and better solution is to have a nested flatbuffer table.  So, table 1 has the bytes which don't mutate.  Table 2 has the few bytes which I do mutate.  This will be more efficient than copying an entire array.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least two solutions to this problem.  The second solution is better in my case because it results in less copying of bytes.

1. By creating an intermediate string (and therefore, a copy of the bytes).  Generally with flatbuffers you want to avoid copies, but for my use case, I'm ok with it.
2. Wrap table definitions like this:

```
    table LotsOfData {
        notMutated:[ubyte];
    }

    table TestMutate {
        notMutated:LotsOfData;
        serverId:int32;
    }
```